# Accessing fields of filter object of Datasource in KendoUI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

For this example I'm lifting off code from elsewhere on this site:

```
<script>
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
 data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
 ],
 filter: { field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane" }
});
var filter = dataSource.filter();
console.log(filter.logic);  // displays "and"
console.log(filter.filters[0]); displays '{field: "name", operator: "startswith", value: "Jane"}'
</script>
```

When I try

```
 console.log(filter.filters[0]["field"]);
```

or

```
 console.log(filter.filters[0].field);
```

or

```
 console.log(filter.filters.field);
```

I keep getting the message

> TypeError: fitem.filters[0] is undefined

or similar. I'm looking for the expression that throws out the value "name".

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `TypeError`, it says you're using `fitem.filters[0]`, and nowhere do you declare `fitem` anywhere in the posted code. That's likely your issue.

It works just fine using `filter.filters[0].field`. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohgross/f41Ltcws/1/) that shows it in action.

It is probably either a scope issue or you are somehow calling it before the declaration of the datasource. Can you provide more code?

Comment: You are correct. Actually this is in a Multiselect and the error comes up because it's trying to filter once the field has focus. I've prevented this by doing a typeof == undefined check before returning the parametermap so it now fires only when the object is defined. I'm sure there is amore efficient way to do this though.